# I have Connection reset Error whilst running PySpark with 150 million rows of data

Tags: python, java, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

The code below gives me the error. I have searched for solutions but to no avail.

```
volume_filter_df = result_df.filter(result_df.BILLINGERRORCODE == '0')

# Filter out rows where 'CATEGORY' is not null
filtered_df = volume_filter_df.filter(volume_filter_df['CATEGORY'].isNotNull())

# Perform the aggregation
volume_analysis = filtered_df.groupby('CATEGORY').agg(func.count('TRANSACTIONTYPE').alias('Count'))
volume_analysis.show()
```

This is the error I get.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o189.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 25.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 46) (LT-IT-263.C.COM executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I tried the below solutions but it didn't work.

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
```

Comment: You can start a always running Spark Logs History server and view the individual executor logs to investigate more. Here's how to do it. It will help you pinpoint why the connection was reset. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqdUGCMRHS4